# How to compare Tuples with a custom Comparer for entries, but the default Comparer for the Tuple?

Tags: c#, tuples, icomparer

I want to sort a `List<Tuple<Vertex, Vertex>>`, i.e. a list of tuples, where each tuple contains a certain amount of vertices.
`Vertex` is a custom class, `List` and `Tuple` are from `System`.

I already have several `Comparer`s that provide a way to compare two vertices, e.g.:
`class MyVertexComparer1 : Comparer<Vertex>` and `class MyVertexComparer2 : Comparer<Vertex>`

Now I would like to use these existing `Comparer`s to sort the list according to the default tuple comparision, i.e. comparing the first entry and only in case of a tie comparing the next entry.
The comparision of two tuples within this sorting should be determined by one of the custom VertexComparers.

I know I could write a `class MyTupleComparer : Comparer<Tuple<Vertex, Vertex>>` that uses the `MyVertexComparer` in its implementation, maybe with a generic parameter that specifies which VertexComparer to use.
However, this feels wrong as I would simply repeat the default comparision for tuples.
Moreover, I do not see how this could be extended to tuples with more than two vertices without a dedicated comparer class for each number of vertices.

Comment: Could you please clarify the use of default vs custom comparers during the sort? It looks like the default comparer does what you want, based on my understanding of what you're asking. If you call `Sort()` on your list, what's wrong with the resulting order?

Comment: @CoolBots I have updated the question, I hope that clarifies the usages of custom and default comparers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `Vertex` an `IComparable<Vertex>`, and the default `Sort` on `List<T>` will work as you describe; that is, a default comparer will be used for `Tuple`, since no custom comparer is provided, and the `Vertex.CompareTo` method will be used for the entries.

If you want to reuse your existing `Comparer`s, you can delegate/share the functionality with the `IComparable<Vertex>.CompareTo` implementation; but you can't do what you want without either writing another `Comparer` for `Tuple` (it'd be for each kind of `Tuple`, since `Tuple<T1, T2>` is a *different type* than `Tuple<T1, T2, T3>`), or implementing `IComparable<Vertex>` on `Vertex` type.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is my understanding correct, that making the `Vertex` an `IComparable` would define one kind of comparision for the vertices? If not, how could I define several ways to compare vertices with the `IComparable<Vertex>` approach?

Comment: It would effectively define a *default entrypoint method* for comparing `Vertex` type; within that method, you can still write logic to delegate comparison to other methods as necessary. For instance, your `Vertex` type can have a constructor that accepts a `Comparer`, or an array of `Comparer`s, that can be used within the   `CompareTo` method, depending on some logic, values, etc.

Comment: Okay, I guess I will stick to the `Comparer` for `Tuple` in order to keep the list sorting variants separate from the `Vertex` data class. Still good to know that there is no way to reuse the default comparisons that way.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody stumbles upon this in the future: Here is the generic implementation I ended up with.
This has the drawbacks that I wished to avoid, but it at least reuses the existing `Comparer`s transparently.

```
class ComparePair<TComp> : Comparer<Tuple<Vertex, Vertex>> where TComp : Comparer<Vertex>, new() {
    private readonly TComp comp = new TComp();

    public override int Compare(Tuple<Vertex, Vertex> a, Tuple<Vertex, Vertex> b) {
        int res = comp.Compare(a.Item1, b.Item1);
        return res == 0 ? comp.Compare(a.Item2, b.Item2) : res;
    }
}
```